Regular map $(\mathbf R^2)^3 \to \mathbf R^6$ such that fibres correspond to unordered triangles
I am working through lecture notes about invariant theory and one of the problems is giving me serious headache.
Interpret $\mathbf R^6 = (\mathbf R^2)^3 = \{(x_1,y_1,x_2,y_2,x_3,y_3) : x_i,y_i \in \mathbf R\}$ as the set of ordered triangles in $\mathbf R^2$ (including degenerated ones). The group $\mathrm S_3$ acts on this set by permuting the three points. The orbits of this action correspond to unordered triangles. Find six real polynomials such that the fibres of the resulting regular map $F \colon \mathbf R^6 \to \mathbf R^6$ are exactly the orbits of the action.
My first idea was to take the elementary symmetric polynomials $\mathrm E_i(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ and $\mathrm E_i(y_1,y_2,y_3)$. From their values, all $x_i$ and all $y_i$ can be reconstructed while their order is order is forgotten. The problem is that this allows the $x_i$ to be permuted independently from the $y_i$.
I tried to add more polynomials (I hope there is a way to reduce the number later) to fix this issue. I thought about $\mathrm E_i(x_1+y_1,x_2+y_2,x_3+y_3)$ to also fix the set of sums $x_i + y_i$. This doesn't work either, as these polynomials cannot tell the triangles $\{(0,1),(1,2),(2,0)\}$ and $\{(0,2),(1,0),(2,1)\}$ apart.
I tried some more polynomials, but couldn't find a set that gives the right fibres. Not even one with way more than six elements.
Is it worthwhile to find a set of polynomials that generate the entire ring of invariants $\mathrm R[X_i,Y_i : 1 \leq i \leq n]^{\mathrm S_3}$? If yes, is there an easier way to do this than going through each homogeneous degree on its own, finding the invariants, and then eliminating those already produced by lower degrees?

Why not treat $\mathbb{R}^6$ (even equivariantly) as $\mathbb{C}^3$ and take symmetric polynomials in $\mathbb{C}[X,Y,Z]$?

@Exitpath Never thought of that. That's probably the easiest solution. Do you want to post that as an answer, so I can accept?

Are you sure that the image is going to $\mathbb R^6$. I have the feeling you need more polynomials. Where did you read this question.

@FedericoFallucca This is just the fact that symmetric group invariants of a polynomial ring also form a polynomial ring in the same number of variables

Yeah okay but the number of polynomial can be bigger than the number of variables.

But there is never a need for more polynomials than the number of variables, if I understood correctly.

@FedericoFallucca I’m not sure what your point is. Very precisely, we’re looking at the quotient map $\mathbb{A}^3=Spec(C[X,Y,Z]) \to Spec(C[X,Y,Z]^{S_3}) \cong \mathbb{A}^3$. Under the latter isomorphism the coordinates go to the elementary symmetric polynomials, of which there are three in this case (which gives six polynomials if working with real coordinates)

This solution is not mine, but proposed by @Exitpath in the comments (You are still encouraged to post this answer yourself for the reputation, I will delete this one then.).
Interpret $(x_j,y_j)$ as the complex number $z_j = x_j + y_j\mathrm i$. The elementary symmetric polynomials in the $z_j$ are
\begin{align*}
\mathrm E_1(\underline z) &= z_1 + z_2 + z_3 \\ &= (x_1 + x_2 + x_3) + (y_1 + y_2 + y_3)\mathrm i \\
\mathrm E_1(\underline z) &= z_1 z_2 + z_1 z_3 + z_2 z_3\\ &= (x_1x_2 + x_1x_3 + x_2x_3 - y_1y_2 - y_1y_3 - y_2y_3) \\
&\quad+ (x_1y_2 + x_2y_1 + x_1y_3 + x_3y_1 + x_2y_3 + x_3y_2)\mathrm i\\
\mathrm E_1(\underline z) &= z_1z_2z_3 \\ &= (x_1x_2x_3 - x_1y_2y_3 - x_2y_1y_3 - x_3y_1y_2) + (x_1x_2y_3 + x_1x_3y_2 + x_2x_3y_1 - y_1y_2y_3)\mathrm i.
\end{align*}
Therefore the six polynomials
\begin{align*}
F_1 &= x_1 + x_2 + x_3 \\
F_2 &= y_1 + y_2 + y_3 \\
F_3 &= x_1x_2 + x_1x_3 + x_2x_3 - y_1y_2 - y_1y_3 - y_2y_3 \\
F_4 &= x_1y_2 + x_2y_1 + x_1y_3 + x_3y_1 + x_2y_3 + x_3y_2 \\
F_5 &= x_1x_2x_3 - x_1y_2y_3 - x_2y_1y_3 - x_3y_1y_2 \\
F_6 &= x_1x_2y_3 + x_1x_3y_2 + x_2x_3y_1 - y_1y_2y_3
\end{align*}
work. If their values are known, one can calculate $a_j = \mathrm E_j(\underline z)$. Then the $z_j$ are the negatives of the roots of $T^3 + a_1T^2 + a_2T + a_3$, in some order. Extract $x_j$ and $y_j$ as their real and imaginary parts.

I suggest also this other method that does not use the identification of $(\mathbb R^2)^3$ as $\mathbb C^3$. Maybe you can find it also useful.
Your question can be reduced from a geometric point of view on how you can determine a triangle on a plane (so the position of the three points defining the triangle) without considering the order of the three points. In other words, it is asking: what are the objects associated to a triangle that reconstruct the triangle itself by determining the three vertex?
For instance, one of these objects is for sure the barycentre  of the triangle: $B:=\left(\frac{x_1+x_2+x_3}{3}, \frac{y_1+y_2+y_3}{3} \right)$.
This is giving you the first two polynomials invariant by the action of $S_3$, as you can easily verify. Now the point is what else is missing to reconstruct the triangle?
From this point I am not good enough as a classical geometer and I don't see a geometric way to determine the triangle from the barycentre plus something else.
The only way I see it is to use algebra and compute a set of invariant generators for the invariant ring $\mathbb R[x_1,y_1,x_2,y_2,x_3,y_3]^{S_3}$.
It is easy to prove that the invariant polynomials of degree $1$ are generated by the above two polynomials.
The invariant polynomial of degree $2$ are for sure $x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2$ and $y_1^2+y_2^2+y_3^2$. However, you can also consider $x_1y_1+x_2y_2+x_3y_3$ that it is still invariant.
Are there other invariant polynomials of degree $2$? Of course yes, but you can prove that all of them are generated by the five above polynomials. As an example, you can see that $x_1x_2+x_1x_3+x_2x_3$ is invariant too, but this can be written as
$$(x_1+x_2+x_3)^2=x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2+2(x_1x_2+x_1x_3+x_2x_3) \implies x_1x_2+x_1x_3+x_2x_3=\frac{9(\frac{x_1+x_2+x_3}{3})^2-(x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2)}{2} $$
Now let us go on the the polynomials of degree $3$. Here you have several other invariant polynomials such as $x_1x_2x_3$ and $y_1y_2y_3$. In particular, we select the polynomials
$$x_1^3 + x_2^3 + x_3^3,\qquad 
    y_1^3 + y_2^3 + y_3^3, \qquad 
    x_1 y_1 x_2 + x_1 y_1x_3 + x_1x_2y_2 + x_1x_3y_3 + x_2y_2x_3 + x_2x_3y_3, \qquad 
    x_1y_1y_2 + x_1y_1y_3 + y_1x_2y_2 + y_1x_3y_3 + x_2y_2y_3 + y_2x_3y_3.$$
It is not so difficult to prove that
$$f_1:x_1+x_2+x_3, \qquad f_2:=y_1+y_2+y_3, \qquad f_3:=x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2, f_4:= \qquad f_4:=y_1^2+y_2^2+y_3^2, \qquad f_5:=x_1^3 + x_2^3 + x_3^3, \qquad f_6:=y_1^3 + y_2^3 + y_3^3$$
and
$$h_1:=x_1y_1+x_2y_2+x_3y_3, \qquad h_2:=x_1 y_1 x_2 + x_1 y_1x_3 + x_1x_2y_2 + x_1x_3y_3 + x_2y_2x_3 + x_2x_3y_3, \qquad h_3:=x_1y_1y_2 + x_1y_1y_3 + y_1x_2y_2 + y_1x_3y_3 + x_2y_2y_3 + y_2x_3y_3$$
are a set of primary and secondary invariants, so that we have
$$\mathbb R[x_1,y_1,x_2,y_2,x_3,y_3]^{S_3} =\bigoplus_{j=1}^3 \mathbb R[f_1,f_2,f_3,f_4,f_5,f_6]\cdot h_j $$
and this means the invariant ring is generated by these nine polynomials as a $\mathbb R$-algebra.
The relations among the above nine polynomials are five, that are the zero locus of the following polynomials:
$$ T_1(f_1,\dots, f_6,h_1,h_2,h_3):=-\frac{1}{6}f_1f_2^2f_3 - \frac{1}{6}f_1^3f_4 + \frac{2}{3}f_1f_3f_4 + \frac{1}{6}f_2^2f_5 - \frac{1}{2}f_4f_5 + 
        \frac{1}{6}f_1^2f_2h_1 - \frac{1}{2}f_2f_3h_1 + \frac{1}{3}f_1h_1^2 + \frac{1}{3}f_1f_2h_2 - h_1h_2 - 
        \frac{1}{6}f_1^2h_3 + \frac{1}{2}f_3h_3, $$
$$ T_2(f_1,\dots, f_6,h_1,h_2,h_3):=-\frac{1}{6}f_2^3f_3 - \frac{1}{6}f_1^2f_2f_4 + \frac{2}{3}f_2f_3f_4 + \frac{1}{6}f_1^2f_6 - \frac{1}{2}f_3f_6 + 
        \frac{1}{6}f_1f_2^2h_1 - \frac{1}{2}f_1f_4h_1 + \frac{1}{3}f_2h_1^2 - \frac{1}{6}f_2^2h_2 + \frac{1}{2}f_4h_2 + 
        \frac{1}{3}f_1f_2h_3 - h_1h_3, $$
$$ T_3(f_1,\dots, f_6,h_1,h_2,h_3):=-\frac{1}{6}f_1^2f_2^2f_3 - \frac{1}{6}f_2^2f_3^2 - \frac{1}{6}f_1^4f_4 + \frac{2}{3}f_1^2f_3f_4 + 
        \frac{1}{6}f_3^2f_4 + \frac{1}{3}f_1f_2^2f_5 - \frac{2}{3}f_1f_4f_5 - \frac{1}{3}f_1f_2f_3h_1 + 
        \frac{1}{3}f_2f_5h_1 + \frac{1}{6}f_1^2h_1^2 - \frac{1}{6}f_3h_1^2 + \frac{2}{3}f_1^2f_2h_2 - 
        \frac{2}{3}f_2f_3h_2 - h_2^2 - \frac{1}{3}f_1^3h_3 + \frac{4}{3}f_1f_3h_3 - f_5h_3,$$
$$ 
   T_4(f_1,\dots, f_6,h_1,h_2,h_3):=-\frac{2}{9}f_1f_2^3f_3 - \frac{2}{9}f_1^3f_2f_4 + \frac{11}{9}f_1f_2f_3f_4 + \frac{5}{18}f_2^3f_5 - 
        \frac{7}{6}f_2f_4f_5 + \frac{5}{18}f_1^3f_6 - \frac{7}{6}f_1f_3f_6 + f_5f_6 - \frac{1}{9}f_1^2f_2^2h_1 - \frac{1}{6}f_2^2f_3h_1 - \frac{1}{6}f_1^2f_4h_1 + \frac{1}{3}f_3f_4h_1 + \frac{4}{9}f_1f_2h_1^2 - 
        \frac{1}{3}h_1^3 + \frac{5}{18}f_1f_2^2h_2 - \frac{1}{6}f_1f_4h_2 + \frac{5}{18}f_1^2f_2h_3 - 
        \frac{1}{6}f_2f_3h_3 - h_2h_3,$$
$$T_5(f_1,\dots, f_6,h_1,h_2,h_3):=-\frac{1}{6}f_2^4f_3 - \frac{1}{6}f_1^2f_2^2f_4 + \frac{2}{3}f_2^2f_3f_4 - \frac{1}{6}f_1^2f_4^2 + 
        \frac{1}{6}f_3f_4^2 + \frac{1}{3}f_1^2f_2f_6 - \frac{2}{3}f_2f_3f_6 - \frac{1}{3}f_1f_2f_4h_1 + 
        \frac{1}{3}f_1f_6h_1 + \frac{1}{6}f_2^2h_1^2 - \frac{1}{6}f_4h_1^2 - \frac{1}{3}f_2^3h_2 + \frac{4}{3}f_2f_4h_2 
        - f_6h_2 + \frac{2}{3}f_1f_2^2h_3 - \frac{2}{3}f_1f_4h_3 - h_3^2.$$
Let us consider the polynomial ring $\mathbb R[X_1,\dots, X_6, Y_1,Y_2,Y_3]$. Then we have an isomorphism
$$ \frac{\mathbb R[X_1,\dots, X_6, Y_1,Y_2,Y_3]}{\langle T_1, T_2,\dots T_5\rangle} \to \mathbb R[x_1,y_1,x_2,y_2,x_3,y_3]^{S_3},\qquad  X_i\mapsto f_i, \quad Y_i\mapsto h_i.$$
The spectrum of $\frac{\mathbb R[X_1,\dots, X_6, Y_1,Y_2,Y_3]}{\langle T_1, T_2,\dots T_5\rangle}$ is the variety in $\mathbb R^9$ defined by the zero locus of $T_1, T_2, \dots, T_5$. The points on this variety are in one-to-one correspondence with the $S_3$-orbits  in $(\mathbb R^2)^3$, so that the quotient map whose fibres are the orbits by the $S_3$-action is
$$\left( \mathbb R^2\right)^3\to Z(T_1, \dots, T_5)\subseteq \mathbb R^9, \qquad ((x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2),(x_3,y_3))\mapsto (f_1,\dots, f_6,h_1,h_2,h_3).$$
As you can see we need in this construction $9$ polynomials instead of $6$. Instead, identifying $(\mathbb R^2)^3$ with $\mathbb C^3$ it is enough to use $6$ polynomials, those suggested by Exit path and founded by Tzimmo.

Actually, @Exitpath pointed out that for abstract reasons there is a set of six polynomials doing the job. They also gave an idea how to explicitly find six such polynomials.

Ah yeah, now I understood what you mean. Thank you very much
